# Difference Between DBCursor and MongoCursor Available in MongoDB Java driver API Doc

Tags: java, mongodb

I am working on MongoDB with  MongoDB java driver 3.8. I am wondering if someone could help me to understand the difference between DBCursor and MongoCursor as I can see both are present in mongo driver API doc. Which one is better to use?

Comment: Have you gone through the doc, one is an interface and another is class... etc?
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/index.html?com/mongodb/Cursor.html and http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/index.html?com/mongodb/Cursor.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of driver version 3.2 `DB`, `DBCollection`, and `DBCursor` classes got deprecated, among few others; but to give the users some time to migrate to the new API without experiencing a huge number of compiler warnings they are still available in later versions, too.

The new equivalents are `MongoDatabase`, `MongoCollection`, and `MongoCursor`.

Reference: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/Mongo.html#getDB-java.lang.String-

Comment: Thanks, Andrea. for your quick response. I wanted to make sure if DB, DBCollection, and DBCursor are deprecated or not. You made the point clear.